# Add total column to cross tab pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I add a total column to this query?

```
SELECT YearOfAccount, [Completed] AS Closed, [Open] AS Opened
FROM 
(SELECT YearOfAccount, Status, CaseCode
FROM Records ) myRecords 
PIVOT
(
COUNT(CaseCode)
FOR [Status] IN
( [Completed], [Open])
) AS pvt
```

Currently I am getting back the results I want but I want to include a total column on the far right for all records that are completed or Open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
, [Completed] + [Open] AS Total
```

to the `SELECT` list